# How do you fix this privacy leak?

Tags: java, encapsulation

I am using java for this code.
I created a class that has two private variables. I have a constructor that takes two dates as arguments, a copy constructor, a default constructor and a setter for each variable. It also has a getter method for each variable that I am not including.

```
public class TripPart{
    private Date start;
    private Date end;

    public TripPart (Date date, Date date2){
        if ((date == null && date2 == null) || date == null || date2 == null) {
            start = date;
            end = date2;
        }
        else {
            boolean before2 = date.before(date2);
            if (before2) {
                start = date;
                end = date2;
            }
            else {
                start = date;
                end = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public TripPart(){
        start = new Date();
        Calendar newEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
        newEnd.setTime(start);
        newEnd.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
        end = newEnd.getTime();
    }

    public TripPart (TripPart toCopy){
        this(toCopy.start,toCopy.end);
    }

    public void setStart(Date date) {
        if (end != null) {
            if (date.before(end)) {
                start = date;
            }
            
        }
        else {
            start = date;
        }
    }

    public void setEnd(Date date) {
        if (start != null) {
            if (date.after(start)) {
                this.end = date;
            }
        }
        else {
            this.end = date;
        }
    }
```

The test I am running keeps failing the encapsulation test.

```
public class TripPartTest{
    private Date getDate(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructor_startEncapsulation(){
         
        Date argumentstart = getDate(2019,11,28,10,25);
        TripPart c = new TripPart(argumentstart,null);

        argumentstart.setTime(getDate(2020,10,20,14,0).getTime());

        Date expectedstart = getDate(2019,11,28,10,25);

        assertEquals("Changed argument after creation from 2019:11:20:10:25 to 2020:10:20:14:00, expect TripPart start to remain unchanged.", expectedstart.toString(), c.getStart());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_setter_and_getter_start_setterEncapsulation(){
         
        Date dep = getDate(2019,11,28,10,20);
        TripPart c = new TripPart(dep, getDate(2019,11,28,11,21));

        dep.setTime(getDate(2018,11,28,8,0).getTime());

        Date expectedstart = getDate(2019,11,28,10,20);
        assertEquals("Changed start time provided as argument to setstart to 2018 from 2019, testing that start in TripPart unchanged", expectedstart.toString(), c.getStart());
    }
```

When the argumentStart and dep are changed after the method is called in the test, it changes the the TripPart. I am unsure how to prevent this.

I have tried the above code, direct assignment and this.start direct assignment.

Comment: It's not clear to me specifically which operation you're referring to, but the description and terminology you're using implies that you may have multiple references to the same object and are expecting them to be different object instances?

Comment: The best thing to do is to avoid using the `Date` and `Calendar` classes.  These have been obsolete for many years now.  It looks to me like the class you want is `LocalDateTime`, from the `java.time` package.  This also has the benefit of being immutable, which makes encapsulation slightly easier.

Answer (score 1):

That 'encapsulation' error is referring to a mutability issue.

When you have an object whose value can be modified by calling methods on it (or directly meddling with its fields), then you have the following problem:

If you hand your object to code outside of your control, *or* you received this object from code that is outside of your control, **that object can change at any time completely beyond your control**.

In other words, that test you do where you create a `TripPart` object and then *afterwards* change the time of object referred to by the `dep` variable, and test that this indeed changes the start time of the `TripPart` instance? **That is in fact precisely what should not be happening**.

That is an 'encapsulation error'.

Imagine that you want your TripPart getup to **guarantee** that start is always before end. That's not a crazy thing to desire. It's convenient: When I receive a `TripPart` object I don't want to have to bother with even thinking about what 'end is in fact *before* start' even means. In fact, your constructor even takes some pains to cater to this, disregarding any attempt to set an enddate that is *after* the start date.

**But this is now a pointless exercise** - after all, I can simply pass 'today' and 'tomorrow' to your constructor which is fine, and then change the 'tomorrow' entry to actually be yesterday, and this act will not magically re-run your constructor-based check. Now I have a 'broken' TripPart object whose start is in fact before end.

That's just a trivial example: If you don't encapsulate (allow outside code to modify your insides independently), there is *no point at all* checking any sort of constraint.

"Encapsulation failure" isn't a code error in the sense that it means your code is definitely not functional or won't compile. It's a **style hint**: You are running some additional software checking tool (generally called a 'linter') that scans your code for things that are *likely* indicating the code is of bad quality, and is detecting an encapsulation error.

### Fixing it

*NB: This general fix is actually a really bad idea here, I strongly advise against it for this situation; pick the second strategy instead!*

*Generally*, you fix encapsulation errors by making defensive copies: Instead of just storing the `date` and `date2` refs you get in your first constructor straight into fields, make copies instead. Now the caller can mess with the date objects they passed all they want; it won't affect your code.

Unfortunately, this defensive copy thing cuts both ways: You can't hand out your internal, modifiable fields either (and `Date` objects are modifiable). Instead, you *also* have to make a defensive copy then. That's a lot of copying. Quite annoying.

### The better fix

Immutable data types. These are data types that simply don't have ways to change them. At best, there are ways to ask them to clone themselves with some modification.

Here is a trivial example you're no doubt familiar with - `String` - which is an immutable data type (mostly <sup>1</sup>).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String a = "Hello!";
  a.toLowerCase();
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

This code prints... `Hello!`. **With a capital `H`**. Why? Because `.toLowerCase()` *does not modify the string at all*. It merely makes a modified clone: It makes an entirely new string (`"hello!"`) and returns *that*. That's because strings cannot be modified. They have no `set` methods nor any other method to modifies its (easily observable) internals.

Hence, there is no need to encapsulate. You can hand any strings that comprise your internal state out like candy or accept an incoming string without making defensive copies of it. Because nobody can change these strings, they can only make new ones, which doesn't matter to your code.

### The specific fix for your code: `java.time`

`java.util.Date` (and `java.util.Calendar`) are **obsolete**. Java-the-core-lib intentionally does not mark core features that are obsolete as '`@Deprecated`' for complicated and possibly faulty reasons, but it is what it is. Nevertheless, these types **should never be used**. Their API is bad (three quarters of all methods in Date are actually `@Deprecated`, which core-libs almost never do, this is only done for methods that are so fundamentally broken they are impossible to fix), their names are lies (a `Date` does not represent a date at all, they represent a moment in time. a `Calendar` instance also does not represent a calendar (it.. also represents a moment in time).

The right API to use is `java.time` - specifically, `java.time.Instant`, `java.time.ZonedDateTime`, or `java.time.LocalDateTime`, depending on your needs. (one of the things the new API gets right is the realisation that there are different reckonings of the notion of time that are mutually incompatible. Any date/time API with only one type representing a time is necessarily broken). Fortunately, all these types **are immutable**.

No need to worry about encapsulation for those.

So that's what you should do. Ditch Date (and Calendar). Use the various things from the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

[1] 'immutable' is a nebulous concept. String is generally immutable, but, not quite - for example, it has a 'hashcodes are fast' property that can be mutated by invoking `hashCode()` on a string, and can be observed by timing the runtime of `hashCode()`. If your program depends on the time taken by a hashCode() call, you're... clearly doing something very very crazy, so the fact that strings aren't quite entirely immutable in this regard, is (or certainly should be to any sane code) irrelevant. Point is, immutable is not a well defined concept if you try to lock it down *exactly*. But for most practical purposes, it's clear, and for most practical purposes, all strings are immutable.

Comment: Since “deprecated” has a specific, technical meaning in Java, I would probably use the word “obsolete” instead.